# Phonegap Build malformed config.xml

Tags: android, xml, cordova, phonegap-build

This is my config.xml file created using confiGAP desktop app.I am getting malformed config.xml error while trying to build using Adobe phonegap build.Please,help me how to solve this error. this is my first app through phonegap

```
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<widget xmlns = "http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets"
    xmlns:gap = "http://phonegap.com/ns/1.0"
    xmlns:android = "http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    id        = "in.destinyahead.app"
    versionCode="1.0.0"
    version   = "1.0.0">
    <name>destinyahead.in       </name>
    <description>Now enjoy your favourite site on your mobile with our brand new app        </description>
    <author href="https://mvnaidu.in" email="mvn@destinyahead.in">M VENKAT NAIDU        </author>
    <feature name="http://api.phonegap.com/1.0/battery" />
    <feature name="http://api.phonegap.com/1.0/camera" />
    <feature name="http://api.phonegap.com/1.0/contacts" />
    <feature name="http://api.phonegap.com/1.0/file" />
    <feature name="http://api.phonegap.com/1.0/geolocation" />
    <feature name="http://api.phonegap.com/1.0/media" />
    <feature name="http://api.phonegap.com/1.0/network" />
    <feature name="http://api.phonegap.com/1.0/notification" />
    <preference name="phonegap-version" value="cli-6.3.0" />
    <preference name="android-build-tool" value="gradle" />
    <preference name="orientation" value="default" />
    <preference name="fullscreen" value="true" />
    <preference name="target-device" value="universal" />
    <preference name="webviewbounce" value="true" />
    <preference name="prerendered-icon" value="false" />
    <preference name="stay-in-webview" value="true" />
    <preference name="ios-statusbarstyle" value="default" />
    <preference name="detect-data-types" value="true" />
    <preference name="exit-on-suspend" value="true" />
    <preference name="show-splash-screen-spinner" value="true" />
    <preference name="auto-hide-splash-screen" value="true" />
    <preference name="FadeSplashScreen " value="true" />
    <preference name="EnableViewportScale" value="false" />
    <preference name="MediaPlaybackRequiresUserAction" value="false" />
    <preference name="AllowInlineMediaPlayback" value="true" />
    <preference name="BackupWebStorage" value="none" />
    <preference name="TopActivityIndicator" value="white" />
    <preference name="KeyboardDisplayRequiresUserAction" value="true" />
    <preference name="KeyboardShrinksView " value="true" />
    <preference name="HideKeyboardFormAccessoryBar" value="true" />
    <preference name="SuppressesIncrementalRendering" value="false" />
    <preference name="windows-appx-target" value="uap" />
    <preference name="windows-arch" value="anycpu" />
    <preference name="windows-identity-name" value="" />
    <preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="14" />
    <preference name="android-targetSdkVersion" value="23" />
    <preference name="android-maxSdkVersion" value="0" />
    <preference name="android-installLocation" value="auto" />
    <preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="2000" />
    <preference name="ErrorUrl" value="null" />
    <preference name="BackgroundColor" value="0x000000" />
    <preference name="DisallowOverscroll" value="true" />
    <preference name="LoadingDialog" value="," />
    <preference name="LoadUrlTimeoutValue" value="null" />
    <platform name="ios">
    <splash src="pics\1242x2208.png" width="1242" height="2208" /> 
    <splash src="pics\2208x1242.png" width="2208" height="1242" /> 
    </platform>
    <platform name="android">
    <icon src="pics\36x36.png" qualifier="ldpi" />
    <icon src="pics\48x48.png" qualifier="mdpi" />
    <icon src="pics\hdpi.png" qualifier="hdpi" />
    <icon src="pics\xhdpi.png" qualifier="xhdpi" />
    <icon src="pics\xxhdpi.png" qualifier="xxhdpi" />
    <icon src="pics\xxxhdpi.png" qualifier="xxxhdpi" />
    </platform>
    <platform name="winphone">
    </platform>
     <icon src="icon.png" />
    <access origin="www.destinyahead.in" subdomains="true" />
    <access origin="www.youtube.com" subdomains="true" />
    <access origin="www.facebook.com" subdomains="true" />
    <access origin="www.mvnaidu.in" subdomains="true" />
    </widget>
```

Comment: @Venkat Ensure that you dont have any invalid or special characters in your xml including space. Did you copy pasted or edited this XML?

Comment: I copy pasted the code from confiGAP

Comment: @Venkat Try copy pasting the XML in notepad, remove any wanted space,enter and tabs and then copy to actual xml file. Some special character during copy is causing the issue

Comment: It's working now I used online xml formatter and copied the new code

Comment: @Venkat copy paste would definitely be the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Copy pasting XML from some other source would have caused the issue probably due to some special characters like carriage returns or new line feeds. Try copying the XML to notepad or some online formatters and then try using it. It should resolve the issue.